# XBMC Addon: Bad request error when using Greek text as query string

Tags: python, urllib, xbmc

How do I set Greek letters as a query parameter? I have following URL:

```
plugin://plugin.video.xxx-com/?isChannel=0&foldername=%CE%9A%CE%9B%CE%95%CE%9C%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%9D%CE%91+%CE%9F%CE%9D%CE%​95%CE%99%CE%A1A&loggedIn=1&mode=folder&Level=vid
```

Upon browsing this URL i get following error:

```
Error Type: <class 'urllib2.HTTPError'>
Error Contents: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Code Given below:

```
Title = item["Title"].encode('utf-8')
url = build_url({'Level': Level, 'isChannel': 0, 'loggedIn': 1, 'mode': 'folder', 'foldername': Title})

def build_url(query):
    return base_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(query)
```

**Update#3:**

Log shows content of `Title` like that:

```
    Title = Î<9a>Î<9b>Î<95>Î<9c>Î<9c>Î<95>Î<9d>Î<91> Î<9f>Î<9d>Î<95>Î<99>Î¡A

 URL in Youtube =
02:17:46 T:2953850880  NOTICE: plugin://plugin.video.buymetv-com/?isChannel=0&foldername=%CE%9A%CE%9B%CE%95%CE%9C%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%9D%CE%91+%CE%9F%CE%9D%CE%95%CE%99%CE%A1A&loggedIn=1&mode=vid&Level=vid
{'isChannel': ['0'], 'foldername': ['\xce\x9a\xce\x9b\xce\x95\xce\x9c\xce\x9c\xce\x95\xce\x9d\xce\x91 \xce\x9f\xce\x9d\xce\x95\xce\x99\xce\xa1A'], 'loggedIn': ['1'], 'mode': ['vid'], 'Level': ['vid']}
```

Update2:
repr() returns:

```
u'\u03a3\u03a5\u039d\u03a4\u0391\u0393\u0395\u03a3 \u0395\u039b\u039b\u0397\u039d\u0399\u039a\u0395\u03a3'
```

Comment: something corrupted the url (there are non-ascii symbols in it). Could you provide `repr(item["Title"])`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Original Question updated

Comment: the title from the log is ok: `urllib.unquote_plus(foldername).decode('utf-8')` (the result is untranslatable though (GREEK RECIPES)).

Comment: the `repr()` result doesn't correspond to the first url in your question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I get this: `Contents: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)`

I simply did: `f_ = urllib.unquote_plus(Title).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: if you pass **`foldername`** from the log (`'%CE%A3%CE%A5..'`) then you should get the `repr()` result from your question `u'\u03a3\u03a5..'` (meaning: it works as it should). The issue is that `foldername` from the top of your answer (broken) is different from the one at the bottom (valid from the log).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian then where is the issue? `unquote_plus` is not resolving either. How to pass eligible string to url?

Comment: I might have edited my last comment after you've already read it. I repeat: if `item["Title"]` is Unicode (and it is) then your code is fine, the url in the log is fine (`foldername` part) if the server support non-ascii characters here, the shown `repr()` is fine. The only problem is the url the very top of your question: where does it come from?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ok I try to produce relevant content again

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian check **update#3**

Comment: what is the issue? `foldername` decodes to "stolen dreams". Except 'A' should be replace by ['Α'](http://codepoints.net/U+0391)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well you are translating? The actual Greek word is **ΚΛΕΜΜΕΝΑ ΟΝΕΙΡA**

Comment: yes. The last letter seems incorrect. It should be http://codepoints.net/U+0391 Somebody uses look alike characters.

Comment: No idea as I am not a greek. But how do I use this greek string in URL that's the`main concern.

Comment: there is no problem with the code if `isinstance(item["Title"], unicode)`. You can post any of the million Unicode codepoints including greek.

Comment: Then why `404 Bad Request` error?

Comment: do you get `400 Bad Request` if you use `u'\u0391'` at the end instead of the look-alike character?

Comment: **03a3\u** is converted to **%C** etc due to urlencode. Are you saying I don't encode?

Comment: replace `'A'`  with `'%CE%91'` at the end of `foldername`

Comment: I set url to `url = 'plugin://plugin.video.xxx-com/?isChannel=0&foldername=%CE%9A%CE%9B%CE%95%CE%9C%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%9D%CE%91+%CE%9F%CE%9D%CE%​95%CE%99%CE%%CE%911A&loggedIn=1&mode=folder&Level=vid` and it says

` Error Contents: ("Non-ASCII character \\xe2`

Comment: I am trying some other approach because making hard code changes like that is not feasible. Thanks for your constant support!!

Comment: 1. The purpose of replacing `unichr(65)` with `unichr(913)` is to find out whether the server returns the 400 http code for semantic errors. it is a one time change for that one single url. It is *not* meant to be left in the code. 2. There is also an independent issue with non-ascii characters in urls (your code can't produce such value (add `assert isinstance(url, str) and url.decode('ascii')` to the code, fix your copy-paste procedure: is it your editor, your OS, some clipboard utility?) where these urls are coming from? Be methodical, don't try to change more than one thing at a time.